# Numerical Methods tutorials/books/videos for non math knowers

Tags: matlab, math, octave, numerical-methods

I'm currently attending the first year of college at Computer Science. I'm having great problems with something named Numerical Methods because I lack at mathematics. I don't have a basis for math concepts.
Could any of you please tell me a good book, tutorial site or videos of Numerical Methods for people that don't have a clear basic knowledge of mathematics?
I tried looking for something like "Numerical Methods for Dummies", but I didn't find anything equivalent.

Comment: You won't get very far if you don't know math in this area. The problems numerical analysis aim to solve are in mathematical form. You ought to understand the problem thoroughly before trying to set up a potential solution ! I'd suggest rather to learn what you don't know.

Comment: As a side note, this question probably doesn't belong on StackOverflow because it doesn't specifically relate to programming. You get better answers if you pick the right Stack Exchange site - this one would have gone well on math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

For good reference books on numerical methods, you can check out the answers to the question [What is the best book on numerical methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453957/what-is-the-best-book-on-numerical-methods)

Bear in mind that numerical methods are a subfield of Maths. Thus **you do need a clear basic knowledge of mathematics** and you probably need to look for other books (not Numerical Methods ones) to fill your knowledge gaps.

Comment: It's not always the maths. For example at Householder Transformations I can hardly understand the method and what every element from the formulas mean.

Comment: @CatalinVasile: Householder transformations make sense only once you know what an orthogonal matrix is.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Numerical Methods for Scientists and Engineers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486652416)

Answer (score 1):

Try sniffing around the internet for course notes (lecture notes) from other universities, especially for first year/second year *engineering* mathematics (for a general grounding) and numerical methods after that.

My university had very good lecture notes, but I can't distribute them. Other universities are more liberal.

You may also want to check out [MIT OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/), which contains lecture notes and course materials from the Massachusetts Institute of Technology. Some of the lecturers at MIT literally [wrote the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) on their respective field, so you can't go wrong with anything you find there.

Links to interesting courses on MIT OCW:

- [18.330 Introduction to Numerical Analysis](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-330-introduction-to-numerical-analysis-spring-2004/)
- [6.042J Mathematics for Computer Science](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this suits you... but you can try this:
http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html - Numerical Recipes ( http://www.nr.com/ )